# Variable in messagebox returns string and not values

Tags: powershell, variables, registry, messagebox

I'll put the request for installed (32bit) Java versions in one variable:

```
$java={Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*| Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion| Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like "Java ? Up*"}}
```

When I ask

```
&$java
```

it returns the wanted values. 
But when put this variable in a message box:

```
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Javaversion: $java","Softwareversion",0,[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Asterisk)
```

it returns the content of the variable (`{Get-Item...`) and not the Java versions.

What is format for the message box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define `$java` with a [scriptblock](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847893.aspx) (essentially a lambda expression/anonymous function). By using the call operator (`&`) you invoke/execute the scriptblock and in return get the result of the operation(s) defined in therein. However, by putting the variable into a string you insert the string representation of the scriptblock (essentially its definition) into the string.

You should probably simply remove the curly braces, so that `Get-ItemProperty` is executed immediately and the results are assigned to the variable `$java`:

```
$java = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |
        Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion |
        Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like "Java ? Up*"}
```